# Select SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG in groups of five from x amount of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query that will do calculations on a result set, it selects the SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG but doesn't have a reliable criteria.

Here is some of the data that I am working with.

```
ITEM   VALUE  doe
10703   3     01/05/2015 06:48
10703   3     01/05/2015 06:49
10419   -16   01/05/2015 06:54
10259   4     01/05/2015 07:09
10578   5     01/05/2015 07:39
10196   2     01/05/2015 07:52
10580   -16   01/05/2015 08:07
10872   2     01/05/2015 08:22
10872   2     03/05/2015 08:23
10619   6     03/05/2015 08:32
10663   -5    03/05/2015 08:55
10652   -4    03/05/2015 09:09
10637   3     03/05/2015 09:23
10650   -2    04/05/2015 09:35
```

I tried the following SQL  -

```
SELECT t0.*, SUM(t0.VALUE) as SUMA, MAX(t0.VALUE) AS MAX, MIN(t0.VALUE) AS MIN, AVG(t0.VALUE) AS AVG FROM ( SELECT ITEM, VALUE, doe FROM VALUES WHERE doe between '01/05/2015 00:00:00' AND '01/05/2015 23:59:59' ORDER BY doe LIMIT 5 ) t0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT t1.*, SUM(t1.VALUE) as SUMA, MAX(t1.VALUE) AS MAX, MIN(t1.VALUE) AS MIN, AVG(t1.VALUE) AS AVG FROM ( SELECT ITEM, VALUE, doe FROM VALUES WHERE doe between '03/05/2015 00:00:00' AND '03/05/2015 23:59:59' ORDER BY doe LIMIT 5 ) t1
```

ETC...

Results would look like the following

```
SUMA   MAX   MIN  AVG  ITEM   DOE
-1     5     -16  0.2  10703  01/05/2015 06:48
8      10    -5   -1   10652  03/05/2015 08:32
```

This does the job but if there is ever a date with one value in, the group of 5 is incomplete, and this therefore ruins the data as I am using it for Six Sigma Statistics.

Essentially I need to be able to select every five records it sees in groups until it reaches ten groups, I have not been able to find a way how to do this so I was forced to ask for help!

If anyone could advise on what I could do it would be greatly appreciated.

If any more information is needed please ask

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Include desired results. Your example query is really weird, because it doesn't have a `GROUP BY` clause. It also has at least 1 syntax error.

Comment: There is nothing to group by, sorry I will include expected results

Comment: You're using aggregate functions, which cannot be used without grouping.

Comment: The SQL runs for me, and like I said, I am not grouping

Comment: This query definately doesn't run for you, because it contains a syntax error. And if you would fix this, if mysql does the implicit group by on all columns (I'm not sure if it does that), MAX, MIN, AVG en SUM will all be equal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why there's both tables T0/T1 and a UNION involved.  Is that necessary for showing the problem?  Also I think the others are correct, it shouldn't run because you have T0.* in the query so it just won't auto group anything.  A query with only aggregates works though.

As for the problem, I'm not entirely sure what you want, but can't you do a COUNT in your aggregates and exclude any that don't contain 5 rows?